# I am trying to setup of a webhook using Stripe and NextJS 13.2.3

Tags: typescript, next.js, stripe-payments, next.js13

I am able to successfully checkout my cart through the built-in Stripe page, and I am redirected to my successUrl route. My local test webhook is getting called as expected. However, when I include the code to verify that the request came from Stripe, I get some errors.

Here is my webhook in NextJS

```
import { stripe } from "@/lib/stripe"

export async function POST(req: Request){

    const payload = await req.json()
    
    const sig = req.headers.get('stripe-signature') as string
    console.log("sig: ", sig)

    let event;

    const endpointSecret = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET_LOCAL as string

    try {
        console.log("constructing event...")
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return new Response(`Webhook error: ${error}`, {
            status: 400,
        })
    }
    
    return new Response("payment confirmation route received", {
        status: 200,
    })
}
```

I'm using the Stripe CLI listen for the success event
`stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/api/checkout/payment-confirmation`

After checking out my cart I see...

`2023-03-23 15:51:28   --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1MowyjE7TMviQOgJNbXch10w] 2023-03-23 15:51:28   --> charge.succeeded [evt_3MowyhE7TMviQOgJ09e3Q7Hu] 2023-03-23 15:51:29   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3MowyhE7TMviQOgJ0OIjeNoH] 2023-03-23 15:51:29   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3MowyhE7TMviQOgJ0ovhouJM] 2023-03-23 15:51:32  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:3000/api/checkout/payment-confirmation [evt_3MowyhE7TMviQOgJ09e3Q7Hu] 2023-03-23 15:51:32  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:3000/api/checkout/payment-confirmation [evt_3MowyhE7TMviQOgJ0OIjeNoH] 2023-03-23 15:51:32  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:3000/api/checkout/payment-confirmation [evt_1MowyjE7TMviQOgJNbXch10w] 2023-03-23 15:51:32  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:3000/api/checkout/payment-confirmation [evt_3MowyhE7TMviQOgJ0ovhouJM]`

and from NextJS I see...

`StripeSignatureVerificationError: Webhook payload must be provided as a string or a Buffer (https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) instance representing the _raw_ request body.Payload was provided as a parsed JavaScript object instead.  Signature verification is impossible without access to the original signed material.  Learn more about webhook signing and explore webhook integration examples for various frameworks at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing`

I took this to mean that I needed to modify the payload argument somehow. I tried `payload.toString()`, `JSON.stringify(payload)`, using `const buf = Buffer.from(payload)` and various other things, thinking that I need to turn this object into a string or buffer somehow, but I am not understanding the problem. Help is much appreciated!

--Update--

Now I have updated the code but I'm still getting the generic error...

`No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?`

My response to Stripe: "I mean, I think so?!?"

I also tried importing 'micro' or 'raw-body' as I've seen others use, but they would give me various errors, which is why I'm using the one from node. req.body is a ReadableStream,

Argument of type 'ReadableStream | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Buffer'

if I try to pass it as the first argument in constructEvent.

```
import { stripe } from "@/lib/stripe"
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { Buffer } from "node:buffer";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest){
    
    const buf = Buffer.from(req.toString())
// <Buffer 5b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 52 65 71 75 65 73 74 5d>

    const headers = req.headers
    
    const sig = req.headers.get("stripe-signature") as string | string[]
// t=1679...,v1=888050e17...,v0=cc9b94a...
    let event;
    const endpointSecret = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET_LOCAL as string
// whsec_...
    

    try {
        console.log("constructing event...")
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf, sig, endpointSecret)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return new Response(`Webhook error: ${error}`, {
            status: 400,
        })
    }
    
    return new Response("payment confirmation route received", {
        status: 200,
    })
}

export const config = {
    api: {
      bodyParser: false,
    },
  };
```

Comment: You're passing `await req.json()` as the payload, and that's not the raw request. I think you need `req.body`

Answer (score 16):

Instead of using `micro` to buffer the body, simply use `await req.text()` to convert the raw body to a string, then pass the string to `stripe.webhooks.constructEvent`.

Comment: OMG, having the same exact issue as a topic-starter.
Tried almost everything possible, and this `await req.text()` nailed it!

Thank you so much!

Comment: I was stuck on this for so long and this worked for me too! Thanks so much

Comment: Noice, req.text() not req.json() of course!

Answer (score 6):

This works for me. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!,
  {
    apiVersion: '2022-11-15'
  }
)

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const body = await req.text();
  const sig = headers().get('Stripe-Signature') as string;
  const webhookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET!;
  let event: Stripe.Event;

  try {
    if (!sig || !webhookSecret) return;
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig, webhookSecret);
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log(`❌ Error message: ${err.message}`);
    return new Response(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`, { status: 400 });
  }

  if (relevantEvents.has(event.type)) {
    try {
      switch (event.type) {
        case 'product.created':
          break;
        case 'product.updated':
          break;
        default:
          throw new Error('Unhandled relevant event!');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return new Response('Webhook handler failed. View logs.', {
        status: 400
      });
    }
  }
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ received: true }));
}
```

Comment: this worked for me. you can also improve it by using `const sig = req.headers.get('stripe-signature')` instead of importing `headers` separately.

Answer (score 4):

Are the webhooks working on localhost but not after deployed? If all other steps don't help, you are most likely using the wrong webhook secret. Do **not** use the secret from Stripe new tutorial page, even when in test mode, it only works for localhost testing.

[image: Do not use secret from here]

Instead, take the webhook secret from here (after clicking "Reveal")

[image: Get secret from here]

Answer (score 1):

When Stripe sends an Event to your webhook endpoint, they first calculate a signature based on the raw body of the Event. When you process the data, you need to make sure that you look at the same exact raw body that Stripe used. If your code looks at a modified version, even if it just added one space or changed the order of a property, you won't be able to match the signature.

When using stripe-node, it's quite common for developers to struggle with the signature verification. The problem is that various frameworks try to be helpful when they receive JSON and already parse it for consumption. So when you try to access the data, you end up getting a different version of the payload even if the "data" in it is similar.

Your code is using `req.json()` but what you want is to access the exact raw body of the POST request which is usually done via `request.body`. You can refer to Stripe's documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart?lang=node). It's also useful to look at [this popular issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/341) on the Github repo for stripe-node which has numerous alternative solutions depending on your overall environmnent.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I've checked out the links that you shared and tried to implement the webhook in the same way that others have, but their solutions don't seem to be working for me. Is there a 'if all else fails' kind of solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Stripe requires the raw body to calculate a signature, and Next.js is automatically parsing the body. You can disable the body parser and parse the data as a buffer. Here is my solution:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_PRIVATE);

const buffer = (req) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];

    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    req.on('end', () => {
      resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
    });

    req.on('error', reject);
  });
};

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.method === 'POST') {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
    return;
  }

  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  try {
    const body = await buffer(req);

    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      body,
      sig,
      process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Webhook invalid!', error);
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${error.message}`);
  }

  // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
  if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
    const session = event.data.object;

    // Fulfill the purchase...
    console.log('SESSION: ', session);
  }

  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  res.json({ received: true });
};

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default handler;
```

This solution is adapted from:

> https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/examples/webhook-signing/nextjs/pages/api/webhooks.ts

Which I found here:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for sharing eric! I keeping getting the error ...
req.on is not a function
I'm beginning to feel that this is just a problem with this version of NextJS or something, because I basically copied and pasted the nextjs example and it's not working. Maybe has something to do with the new route handlers?

Comment: I copied their solution exactly, changed for my test secret key and still get the same error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?

Answer (score 1):

I've built a Next project integrating Stripe and a webhooks api, it's using the new /app router. I'll leave you the link to the repo so you can take a look at the README.md. https://github.com/BastidaNicolas/nextauth-prisma-stripe

Answer (score 0):

For creating stripe webhook you will need raw body

and in Nextjs 13 you can get the raw body by

```
const body= await req.text()
```

Comment: Next.js does not expose the text() method.

Comment: yeah I found it in a article